# Oracle equivalent of ABORT where in teradata

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception, teradata

In teradata you can do something like this:

```
ABORT    'custome message'
WHERE    :parameter_var NOT IN
(
SELECT
var
FROM    table_name
);
exec delete_something(:parameter_var);
```

What's the equivalent in Oracle. I'm thinking of using exceptions but not sure what the best approach is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like [RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#i3329) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT var into v_dummy from table_name;
    exec delete_something(:parameter_var);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'customer message');
```